# Running a new thread from IntentService

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, intentservice, android-intentservice

Suppose I want my app to sync data from an online database to the local database, I understand Services are the components to look for.

If I start a normal service, I understand that it starts in the main thread and any time-consuming task I run will block the UI. This means that I will have to use something like an AsyncTask to get the job done.

On the other hand, if I use an Intent Service, I understand that it runs on a parallel thread and the UI isn't blocked if I run a long task.
And any other intent service I call will be queued up.

But what will happen if I create a parallel thread from the IntentService to make a network call?

Will the intent service wait for my network call to complete or will it make the call in a parallel thread and execute the next Intent Service in the queue?

Comment: Why you need to create parallel thread in parallel thread to make network call??? Use it in `IntentService` dirrectly

Comment: Why a parallel thread while `if` statement exits?

Comment: I was just curious. I wont make that haha

Answer (score 3):

Only the lifecycle calls (eg: `onCreate()`, `onStartCommand()`) are called on the main (UI) thread in a `Service`. If you have background actitivies, you can just start your own background threads in `onStartCommand()`. You don't need to use `IntentService` for this.

`IntentService` is a specific implementation of `Service` that has a specific behaviour. You send it "work" by calling `startService()` and passing an `Intent` that describes the work to be done. The `IntentService` runs until all of the queued "work" is completed and then shuts itself down. `IntentService` is just a thi8n layer on top of regular `Service` that handles the queueing of the "work", the execution of the "work" in background threads, and the automatic shutdown of the `IntentService`. If this is not exactly the behaviour that you want, you shouldn't try to to use `IntentService`, as it isn't appropriate for all situations. It isn't that difficult to start background threads in a `Service` yourself.

Comment: Sir, Please can you provide an answer for this question  https://stackoverflow.com/q/63350856/5359340