# Can't do heavy work on broadcast receiver which is inside the Service

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, service, broadcastreceiver, phone-state-listener

I created a `Broadcast Receiver` Which is inside the `Service Class` (Because of the Android `Broadcast receiver` restrictions `Broadcast receiver` stops after while, So I created `Background Service`, with foreground `Service Notification` **Restriction in Android Oreo=<** ). This `Broadcast Receiver` Listens to Phone Call States Changes **IDLE, OFFHOOK, RINGING**. According to the Phone call states changes(If the call ends), I get the last call details in the Cursor and Send to that details into the `Firebase Realtime Database`. everything works perfectly until I comment(//) on the `saveDatafromCursor()` method Which is inside the `PhoneStateListener Class`. (I write a Toast message before saving data method). it works very fine. and my service works very well. but if I uncomment my `saveDatafromCursor()` method After the call ended. My Service stops(notification icon and toast messages stop. I checked in the real device). **Without implementing the Service, I  send data to the Firebase it's working very well**, Why My service stops if I try to save data to the firebase?

> Service Class

```
public class HammerService extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter();
        ifilter.addAction(android.telephony.TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED);

        registerReceiver(receiver, ifilter);

    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        String input = intent.getStringExtra("inputExtra");
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                0, notificationIntent, 0);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("Hammer Service")
                .setContentText(input)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_android)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .build();

        startForeground(1, notification);

        //do heavy work on a background thread
        //stopSelf();
        return START_NOT_STICKY;

    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if(action.equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")){
                //action for sms received
            }
            else if(action.equals(android.telephony.TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED)){
                runfirstTime(context,intent);
            }
        }
    };

    private void runfirstTime(Context context, Intent intent) {
        TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        MyPhoneStateListener customPhoneListener = new MyPhoneStateListener();

        telephony.listen(customPhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        String phone_number = bundle.getString("incoming_number");

        String stateStr = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        int state = 0;

        if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)){
            state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
        }
        else if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)){
            state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK;
        }
        else if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){
            state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING;
        }

        if (phone_number == null || "".equals(phone_number)) {
            return;
        }

        customPhoneListener.onCallStateChanged(context, state, phone_number);
    }
}
```

> PhoneStateListener Class

```
public class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {

    private static int lastState = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
    private static Date callStartTime;
    private static boolean isIncoming;

    static boolean calledAlready = false;

    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    private Context ctx;


    public void onCallStateChanged(Context context, int state, String phoneNumber) {
        if (lastState == state) {
            //No change, debounce extras
            return;
        }

        ctx = context;

        System.out.println("Number inside onCallStateChange : " + phoneNumber);

        switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                isIncoming = true;
                callStartTime = new Date();

                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                if (lastState != TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                    isIncoming = false;
                    callStartTime = new Date();

                }
                break;

            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                //Went to idle-  this is the end of a call.  What type depends on previous state(s)
                if (lastState == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                    //Ring but no pickup-  a miss
                    waitforlastcalllog();

                } else if (isIncoming) {

                    //  Toast.makeText(context, "Incoming " + phoneNumber + " Call time " + callStartTime  , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    waitforlastcalllog();
                } else {

                    //  Toast.makeText(context, "outgoing " + phoneNumber + " Call time " + callStartTime +" Date " + new Date() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    waitforlastcalllog();
                }

                break;
        }

        lastState = state;
    }

    private void waitforlastcalllog() {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //String deviceMan = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER;
                String deviceMan = Build.MANUFACTURER;

                String deviceName=deviceMan.toLowerCase();

                if(deviceName.equals("samsung"))
                {
                   // Toast.makeText(ctx, "dvv "+deviceMan, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    getCallLogs("samsung");
                }
                else
                {
                    getCallLogs("other");
                }


            }
        }, 500);

    }

    private void getCallLogs(String devicename) {

        ContentResolver cr = ctx.getContentResolver();
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(ctx, Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        Cursor c = cr.query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

        if (c != null) {

            if(devicename.equals("samsung"))
            {
                if (c.moveToFirst()) { //starts pulling logs from last - you can use moveToFirst() for first logs
                    getCallDetails(c);
                }
            }else
            {
                if (c.moveToLast()) { //starts pulling logs from last - you can use moveToFirst() for first logs
                    getCallDetails(c);
                }
            }

            c.close();
        }
    }

    private void getCallDetails(Cursor c)
    {
        int totalCall=1;

        for (int j = 0; j < totalCall; j++) {

            String call_id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CallLog.Calls._ID));
            String phNumber = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER));
            String callDate = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CallLog.Calls.DATE));
            String callDuration = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CallLog.Calls.DURATION));
            Date dateFormat= new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));
            String callDayTimes = String.valueOf(dateFormat);
            String callerName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME));


            String direction = null;
            switch (Integer.parseInt(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CallLog.Calls.TYPE)))) {
                case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                    direction = "OUTGOING";
                    break;
                case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                    direction = "INCOMING";
                    break;
                case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                    direction = "MISSED";
                    break;
                case CallLog.Calls.VOICEMAIL_TYPE:
                    direction = "VOICEMAIL_TYPE";
                    break;
                case CallLog.Calls.REJECTED_TYPE:
                    direction = "REJECTED_TYPE";
                    break;
                case CallLog.Calls.BLOCKED_TYPE:
                    direction = "BLOCKED_TYPE";
                    break;
                case CallLog.Calls.ANSWERED_EXTERNALLY_TYPE:
                    direction = "ANS EXT TYPE";
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            c.moveToPrevious(); // if you used moveToFirst() for first logs, you should this line to moveToNext

            Toast.makeText(ctx, phNumber + callDuration + callDayTimes + direction +callerName , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // you can use strings in this line
            saveDatafromCursor(phNumber,callDuration,callDayTimes,direction,callerName);
        }
    }


    private void saveDatafromCursor(String phNumber, String callDuration, String callDayTimes, String direction,String callername)
    {
        ModelCursor mc=new ModelCursor();

        mc.setPhoneNumber(phNumber);
        mc.setCallDuration(callDuration);
        mc.setCallDayTimes(callDayTimes);
        mc.setDirection(direction);

        if(callername==null)
        {
            callername="Not in Contacts";
        }

        mc.setCallUsername(callername);


        if (!calledAlready) {
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
            calledAlready = true;
        }

        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        databaseReference = database.getInstance().getReference().child("Call-Details-X");
        String key = databaseReference.push().getKey();

        String android_id = Settings.Secure.getString(ctx.getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);

        Date date=new Date();

        SimpleDateFormat timeStampFormatsearch = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-yyyy-MM");
        String dateofcall = timeStampFormatsearch.format(date);


        databaseReference.child(android_id).child(dateofcall).child(key).setValue(mc).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Logcat - Error

```
2020-08-12 10:03:33.217 5151-5151/com.fooding.callhammer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.fooding.callhammer, PID: 5151
    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Calls to setPersistenceEnabled() must be made before any other usage of FirebaseDatabase instance.
        at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.assertUnfrozen(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:316)
        at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.setPersistenceEnabled(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:284)
        at com.fooding.callhammer.MyPhoneStateListener.saveDatafromCursor(MyPhoneStateListener.java:214)
        at com.fooding.callhammer.MyPhoneStateListener.getCallDetails(MyPhoneStateListener.java:191)
        at com.fooding.callhammer.MyPhoneStateListener.getCallLogs(MyPhoneStateListener.java:138)
        at com.fooding.callhammer.MyPhoneStateListener.access$000(MyPhoneStateListener.java:26)
        at com.fooding.callhammer.MyPhoneStateListener$1.run(MyPhoneStateListener.java:104)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
2020-08-12 10:03:33.446 2016-2122/system_process E/InputDispatcher: channel '276f02e com.fooding.callhammer/com.fooding.callhammer.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
2020-08-12 10:03:36.556 2016-2197/system_process E/TaskPersister: File error accessing recents directory (directory doesn't exist?).
2020-08-12 10:03:48.799 2016-2041/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2020-08-12 10:03:49.499 2016-2048/system_process E/BatteryExternalStatsWorker: no controller energy info supplied for wifi
2020-08-12 10:04:00.018 2016-2041/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
```

Comment: Please check the logcat for errors, exceptions. Don't filter the logcat or you might miss something important. You need to determine what is crashing and why.

Comment: Thank you, sir, your reply is my answer. before I run this in a real device, I thought because of the heavy work broadcast receiver killed service, but the thing is firebase offline capabilities, my app crashes. Now I initialize, in a good way https://stackoverflow.com/a/37766261/5359340, thank you so much for your reply

Answer (score 1):

From documentation: A service runs in the main thread of its hosting process; the service does not create its own thread and does not run in a separate process unless you specify otherwise. You should run any blocking operations on a separate thread within the service to avoid Application Not Responding (ANR) errors. I think that's the reason why you can not do "heavy" work within Service class. I didn't go through your code, but you can do two things:

1.) Make new thread inside service on create and do "heavy work"(don' forget to stop it). https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services

2.) extend JobIntentService class, give it a try. And then override function onHandleWork(intent), where you start "heavy" work.
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/JobIntentService